# How can we show conditional density function with change of variable technique?

Tags: probability

I want to find a conditional density fucntion p(x|y) using a change of variable technique.

First, i tried to estimate p(x|y) based on the formular of bivariate change of variable technique:

Suppose that the transformation $$(z = f_1(x,y), y = f_2(x,y))$$ is defferentiable and has inverse transformation $$(x = f_1^{-1}(z,y), y = f_2^{-1}(z,y)) $$.

Then as i think, we can estimate p(x|y) with change of variable techinque:

$$
p(x,y) = p(z,y)\begin{vmatrix}{}
  dz/dx& dz/dy\\
  dy/dx& dy/dy
\end{vmatrix}
$$
Finally, 
$$p(x,y)/p(y)=p(x|y) = p(z,y)/p(y)= p(z|y)/p(y)\begin{vmatrix}{}
  dz/dx& dz/dy\\
  dy/dx& dy/dy
\end{vmatrix}
$$

However, the value determinant of Jacovian is zero like followings: $$\begin{vmatrix}{}
  dz/dx& dz/dy\\
  dy/dx& dy/dy
\end{vmatrix}=dz/dx * dy/dy - dz/dy*dy/dx=dz/dx  - dz/dy*dy/dx=0
$$

- **In this process, is there something wrong ?**

And, if i am wrong about estimating conditional density function, how can i derive condtional density function with change of varible techniques?

Comment: As i think, there is a mistake in following formula:$$ 
\begin{vmatrix}{}
  dz/dx&dz/dy\\
  dy/dx&dy/dy
\end{vmatrix}
 $$ The corrected form should be like this: $$ 
\begin{vmatrix}{}
  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}
 $$

Comment: Then,  $$ 
\begin{vmatrix}{}
  \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\\
  \frac{\partial y}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial y}{\partial y}
\end{vmatrix}
 $$ is like that $$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial y} - \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $$

Comment: Finally, $$ \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} - \frac{\partial z}{\partial y}*\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} $$ is not zero. Am i right?

Comment: No... have you not read a thing I wrote? This is not some issue with partial vs total derivatives... it is **that you are using $y$ for two different things** ... there are **four** coordinates (two original and two transformed), not three.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a correct way to compute the conditional density, provided the transformation is actually non-singular as you indicate. But in this case, you should not wind up with a Jacobian that vanishes identically.

One problem that jumps out is that you have given the same name $y$ to one of the transformed coordinates and one of the original coordinates. You should give it a new name, perhaps writing $w=f_2(x,y)$ rather than $y=f_2(x,y)$. Once you do that you won't have the apparent nonsense of your Jacobian vanishing identically cause of coincidences.

I'm not sure why you wrote $y=f_2(x,y)$ in the first place. Perhaps in the concrete situation you had, we had $f_2(x,y)=y$. Still here, in the abstract, you need to write $w=f_2(x,y)$ (or be very careful when thinking about the inversion of the functions).

On a side note, it's almost never a good idea to be abstract and "pre-process" your question. This makes the problem you're having harder to diagnose and can lead to issues similar to the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: The real my question is about the this research paper: https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJg3zxBYwH.

Comment: i cannot understand the equation (7) from this paper. So i tried the reformulation. In the reformulation process, maybe serveral mistake and wrong gernerated. Can you try to read this paper and explain how this equation (7) can be derived ??

Comment: @sunghopark Well, this is a bit different. I can see why you thought you had to compute a joint density here, but it's actually quite irrelevant since we're conditioning everything on $\mathbf x$ from the beginning. The functional relationship between $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf z$ also depends on $\mathbf x,$ but again, who cares... $\mathbf x$ is fixed. So this is just a ordinary change of variables between $\mathbf y$ and $\mathbf z$ (only tranforming the *conditional* densities and using the functional relationship for that particular $\mathbf x$) and $\mathbf x$ is just "along for the ride"

Comment: @sunghopark I'm not sure if my short explanation in this comment here is adequate. If not, I'd recommending just asking a new question.

Comment: Thank you for your response. It is very impressive just that there is someone (you) to help me.  Frome the paper, equation (7) is followings: $$ p(y|x) = p(z|x)|\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}| = p(f(y,x)|x)| \frac{\partial f(y,x)}{\partial y}|$$.

Comment: In this equation, (1) why should be bijective function f defined as followings?: forward: z = f(y,x), inverse: y=f(z,x) .  (2) is this equation suitable fomulation for estimating p(y|x) with change of variable ?